# Show that function with bounded derivative is surjective in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n} $ with $\left\| \mathrm{D}_{}f(\mathbf{x})\right\|_{2}\le c< 1$ and
\begin{align*}
    g\colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}, \quad g(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{x})+\mathbf{x}
.\end{align*}
I want to show that $g$ is surjective.
My first thought was to maybe show that the function
\begin{align*}
    d _{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x}) = \left\|g(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{y}\right\|_{2} ^2
\end{align*}
and show that its minimum is attained and equals zero for each $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ but found that this probably won't work
since $\mathrm{D}_{}f(\mathbf{x})$ is not guaranteed to be invertible. A second idea would be to use the fixed point theorem, but I don't know
how I would use it in this case. Could someone maybe help me with this?

I came up with this:

For every $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}$ consider the function
\begin{align*}
    h_\mathbf{y}(\mathbf{x}) =\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y} - g(\mathbf{x})
.\end{align*}
We have
\begin{align*}
    \mathrm{D}_{}h_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}} (\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}+f(\mathbf{x}))
    = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}} (y+f(\mathbf{x})) = \mathrm{D}_{}f(\mathbf{x})
.\end{align*}
By the mean value inequality, for every $\mathbf{x}_{1}, \mathbf{x}_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}  $ we have
\begin{align*}
    \left\|h_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x}_{1})-h_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x}_{2})\right\|_{2} \le \left(\max_{\mathbf{x} \in [\mathbf{x}_{1}, \mathbf{x}_{2}]} 
    \left\|\mathrm{D}_{}f(\mathbf{x})\right\|_{2} \right)\left\|\mathbf{x}_{1}-\mathbf{x}_{2}\right\|_{2} 
    \le c \left\|\mathbf{x}_{1}-\mathbf{x}_{2}\right\|_{2} 
\end{align*}
with $c < 1$ and hence it's a contraction mapping. By the fixed point theorem, the function $h_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x})$ has a unique
fixed point, call it $\mathbf{x}_{0}$. This yields
\begin{align*}
    h_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x}_{0}) =\mathbf{x}_{0} &\iff  \mathbf{x}_{0} + \mathbf{y}- g(\mathbf{x}_{0})=\mathbf{x}_{0}
    \\ 
                                                   &\iff g(\mathbf{x}_{0}) = \mathbf{y}
.\end{align*}

Comment: This seems like a step the the inverse function theorem and it's sometimes called perturbation of identity. You definitely want to use Banach's fixed point theorem. It's just tricky to find the right contraction and invariant complete subset. But once this is done, so is the subjectivity of $g$. Begin by reinterpreting the existence of a solution in $x$ to the equation $f(x)=y$ as the search for a fixed point of a contraction.

Comment: @LázaroAlbuquerque do you think my approach works?

Comment: Yes, your approach is solid.

Comment: The title is wrong and misleading.